# How to refer js file to particular script block only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation where I need to refer a `jqplot.pieRenderer.min.js` file to a particular script block only. Because if it is used globally at the top, it is throwing error for the other scripts block functions. How can i maintain that js file to particular script block.

I tried below.

```
 <script src="jquery.jqplot.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> // global js file
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jqplot.pieRenderer.min.js"> //using specific js
        $(document).ready(function () {
             BindLocationStock();
             BindStatusWiseStock();
        });
 <script type="text/javascript"> //using global js 
        $(document).ready(function () {
             BindBarChart();
        });
```

Can first script block use global js file and block level js file? I want this scenario. How can I achieve this. Please assist here.

Comment: why is a jquery plugin causing errors in other inline scripts?

Comment: Note: A `<script>` cannot be both external and inline. If it has a `src`, the inner text will be ignored.

Comment: @Eevee: Because there is browser specific code issue.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is not possible to do what you are trying to do.

This is one of the reasons why the [module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript) is so useful for JavaScript.

I recommend refactoring your code to use the [module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript) - that way, you won't have global variables interfering with one another.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's conflict issue. Either you can use `jQuery.noConflict` or wrap up your code like this:

```
 <script src="jquery.jqplot.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> // global js file
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jqplot.pieRenderer.min.js"> //using specific js
  (function ($) {
         BindLocationStock();
         BindStatusWiseStock();
         BindBarChart();
    })(jQuery);
```